# Syntax friendly ways to replace an initializer list?

Tags: c++, syntax, initializer-list

I have now in my code a function that generates an `std::vector<SomeHeavyComplexType>` (in the code below just an int):

```
inline std::vector<int> generateComplexConf() {
    return {1,2,3,4,5};
}

struct MyComplexStruct {
   const std::vector<int> my_conf;
   MyComplexStruct() : my_conf(generateComplexConf()) {}
};
```

This works great, but AFAIK initializer lists are const - so the above code will generate an std::vector in `generateComplexConf` then copy it into an element of MyComplexStruct.

A better alternative would be:

```
inline std::vector<int> generateComplexConf() {
    std::vector<int> ret;
    ret.emplace_back(1);
    ret.emplace_back(2);
    ...
    return ret;
}

struct MyComplexStruct {
   const std::vector<int> my_conf;
   MyComplexStruct() : my_conf(std::move(generateComplexConf())) {}
};
```

where now the std::vector<> is just moved.

My questions are:

- Is there a better alternative of the 2 above pieces of code - i.e. have something that would generate something exactly like `MyComplexStruct() : my_conf{1,2,3,4}` but allowing to have the code configuring the object (`{1,2,3,4,5}`) in a different place than directly in the definition of `MyComplexStruct`?
- If there is not, in the code where I use the `std::move`, this forces me to use emplace_back several times (hundreds of times in my actual code). Are you aware of something with a better syntax - i.e. an initializer-list-ish with non-constness?

EDIT:

following the comments, I should add some precisions. To clarify my question, imagine that instead of a `std::vector<int>` it was an `std::vector<Test>` where Test is not copyable, not moveable, not assignable, e.g.:

```
struct Test {
    int a;

    Test(int x) : a(x) {}
    Test() : a(1) {}
    Test(Test&&) = delete;
    Test(const Test&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(Test&&) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&) = delete;
};

inline std::vector<Test> generateConf() {
    return {Test{1},Test{2}};
}

inline std::vector<Test> generateConfMove() {
    std::vector<Test> r;
    r.emplace_back(1);
    r.emplace_back(2);
    return r;
}

struct MyComplexStruct {
   const std::vector<int> my_conf;
   MyComplexStruct() : my_conf(generateConf()) {}
};
```

While `generateConf` will try to use the copy constructor of Test, `generateConfMove` will try to use the move constructor of Test (since as somebody corrected me accordingly in the comments, the `data` of the initializer-list is const).

If I reformulate my 2 questions:

1. In the general case where `Test` is non moveable and non copyable, is there anyway to have the code configuring the object in a different place than the constructor
2. If `Test` in only non copyable, then the emplace_back works fine. But in that case, is there any other more 'syntax-friendly' way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by *AFAIK initializer lists are const*?  Hard to imagine....

Comment: The first version is fine.  In fact, in C++17, it is guaranteed to not even make an object as we have guaranteed RVO

Comment: Pre C++17, as long as the class is moveable, at worst your get move.

Comment: Still not sure what you meant by *AFAIK initializer lists are const*, but if you're thinking you can only assign to `const` data members in an initialiser list, that's wrong: you can make `my_conf` non-`const` in the first version of your code, then modify the `vector` any time later.

Comment: You can make a template function/constructor that forwards arguments to the constructor of `MyComplexStruct` and use that to `emplace_back` into the vector.

Comment: Data in the `initializer_list` is `const`, but the vector created from that is not, and since it is an rvalue it will be moved to the final location (if not constructed there directly due to the magic of NRVO and copy/move elision)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I made the post more accurate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your first cut was perfectly fine - can't be improved on - things just went downhill from there.  The compiler's smart enough to know that when a function returns by value, that value can be elided and constructed directly when the caller assigns it, or - failing that (it wasn't guaranteed to elide pre C++17) - moved from if necessary.

> but allowing to have the code configuring the object ({1,2,3,4,5}) in a different place than directly in the definition of MyComplexStruct?

Nothing better than what you've already done.  If you don't assign in the initialiser list, then the vector data member `my_conf` will be default constructed then you'd have to place values into it later - that's less efficient.